# Default value if %U is empty in .desktop file

Tags: bash, 22.04, .desktop

I'm trying to default open a couple of tabs in Brave on my work computer. I don't want these to open on my personal computer and since my account is synced, I can't use the built in default tabs in Brave.

I modified the Exec command in my .desktop file to the following and it works, but it also opens these tabs when I open a link from another application.

```
Exec=/usr/bin/brave-browser-stable %U "foo" "bar"
```

I want to either set a default value for %U with these 2 urls or only open these 2 urls if %U is empty.

Comment: Use a wrapper script that sets these arguments if no arguments are given

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Read `man bash`. It's a Simple Matter Of Programming (SMOP). Replace your `Exec=` line with `Exec=/path/to/script`

Comment: Could you give me an example?